# In Vue.js, why doesn't my select have the default option selected?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My code is as follows:

https://jsfiddle.net/urjg6fop/

I want "Select value" to be displayed initially, but instead it shows a blank.

My value is `""`, my model is `tracker[city]` and I intialise all the values of `tracker[city]` to be `""` so I would expect the initial value of `Select value` to be displayed, but instead it is blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vue cannot detect dynamic property addition or deletion](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats), which is what you're doing in `mounted()`:

```
this.tracker[city] = ""; // dynamically adding `city` keys to `tracker` object (DON'T DO THIS)
```

You'd have to use [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) or [`this.$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) instead:

```
this.$set(this.tracker, city, "")
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d1c3hnvk/)